# Cypress testing Stripe elements

Tags: reactjs, laravel, stripe-payments, cypress

I have a problem testing stripe elements with cypress. Stripe elements are setup in React, like this:

```
import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import {
    PaymentElement,
    Elements,
    useStripe,
    useElements,
    ExpressCheckoutElement,
    PaymentMethodMessagingElement,
} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';

...

<Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={options}>
    <Payments user={props.customer ? props.customer : props.auth.user} data={props} formData={formData} setStep={(e)=>setStep(e)} setCheckoutError={(e) => setCheckoutError(e)}/>
</Elements>
```

When I run my server in localhost, stripe elements are displayed without any errors, end everything work.

Problem occurs when I run my e2e tests in Cypress. I'm using Cypress `"cypress": "12.17.4"`and `"cypress-plugin-stripe-elements": "^1.0.2"` plugin to easier interact with elements. I'm running tests in `Chrome v120` browser. Everything loads up, and as soon as Stripe elements should be displayed, I get a blank page:

[image: blank elements page]

Upon inspecting my console, I notice these errors:

[image: network errors]

Specifically I see this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'queuedMessages')
```

I'm wondering what is the cause of this error, and how to bypass this, so my stripe elements load on the page.

For reference, here's my cyprees test that is running:

```
it.only("User can create a supplement order with valid data", () => {
    cy.visit("http://127.0.0.1:8000/login");
    cy.regularLogin(); //login user to the account
    cy.addSupplementToBasketFromShop(); //add item to basket and go to checkout page, where elements should be loaded
    cy.get('#supplement_terms').click({force: true});
    cy.get('button[type="submit"]._button.secondary').click();
});
```

The test is running successfully, and elements are loaded for a brief moment. Then, these requests appear, and stripe elements are invisible:

[image: stripe requests]

If you need any additional info, please let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripe's [doc about automated testing](https://stripe.com/docs/automated-testing) indicates you should mock this instead of loading Elements, and that:

> Frontend interfaces, like Stripe Checkout or the Payment Element, have
> security measures in place that prevent automated testing

I would say you might want to consider skipping loading elements in these test sequences by detecting the environment, for example.

Comment: That makes total sense. Thanks for the info! So basically solution is to mock everything, instead of going through the real payment flow.